# WinRT RichEditBox Limitations

Tags: winrt-xaml, richtext

In Windows Store app (XAML/C#), I've created a custom control with 'RichEditBox' in it. I want to limit number of characters (MaxLength) for it or at least vertical scroll bar should be disabled. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to set a limit for the number of characters in a declarative manner, but you may handle the text changed event and do your checks in code behind.

For the scroller you can set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to `Disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this out:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="TextElementControl" 
    Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=userControlModified}" 
    ManipulationMode="None" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
    SizeChanged="TextElementControlSizeChanged"  
    IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
    BorderThickness="0" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
    Padding="10,10,10,10"     
/>
```

Code Behind:

> TextElementControl.TextChanged += TextElementControlTextChanged;

More Code Behind:

> private void TextElementControlTextChanged(object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e)
>           {
>               string str;
>               TextElementControl.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None,
>   out str);
>               TextElementControl.Height = double.NaN;
>
> ```
>         if (str.Trim().Length > 502 && !_loading)
>         {
>             if (popUpReminder == null)
>             {
>                 popUpReminder = new Popup();
>                 popUpReminder.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
>
>                 var panel = new StackPanel();
>                 panel.Background = BlackSolidColorBrush;
>                 panel.Height = 60;
>                 panel.Width = 220;
>
>                 var reminderText = new TextBlock();
>                 reminderText.FontSize = 14;
>                 reminderText.Text = "You have exceeded the maximum number of characters for this textbox.";
>                 reminderText.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
>
>                 reminderText.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
>                 reminderText.Margin = new Thickness(10, 5, 10, 5);
>                 panel.Children.Add(reminderText);
>
>                 Border brder = new Border();
>                 brder.BorderBrush = RedSolidColorBrush;
>                 brder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
>                 brder.Child = panel;
>
>                 popUpReminder.Child = brder;
>                 popUpReminder.HorizontalOffset = Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Width - panel.Width - 10;
>                 popUpReminder.VerticalOffset = Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Bottom - 100 - panel.Height - 10;
>             }
>             popUpReminder.IsOpen = true;
>             TextElementControl.Document.Undo();
>
>
>         } }
> ```